# Does 'attr_reader' make a local variable available throughout a class?

Tags: ruby, attr-accessor

Why is the `type` variable available in the `is_a_peacock?` method in the following?

```
class Animal
    attr_reader :type

    def initialize(type)
        @type = type
    end

    def is_a_peacock?
        if type == "peacock"
            return true
        else
            return false
        end
    end
end

an = Animal.new('peacock')
puts an.is_a_peacock? # => true
```

Why does commenting out the initialization of `@type` make `type` unavailable?

```
class Animal
    attr_reader :type

    def initialize(type)
        #@type = type
    end

    def is_a_peacock?
        if type == "peacock"
            return true
        else
            return false
        end
    end
end

an = Animal.new('peacock')
puts an.is_a_peacock? # => false
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "Why does commenting out the initialization of `@type` make `type` unavailable?"

It does not. Method `type` is available. Just not initialized. Because you commented that out.

If method `type` wasn't available, your program would crash. (As it does when you comment out the `attr_reader`).

Answer (score 1):

You can think of `attr_reader :type` as doing this for you:

```
def type
  @type
end
```

But it *does not* automatically assign instance variables based on what you pass into the initializer, like you seem to assume it would do.

Since you no longer do `@type = type`, `@type` stays at its default value of `nil`. Every instance variable is nil by default.

On a side note, instead of

```
   if type == "peacock"
        return true
    else
        return false
    end
```

you can write just

```
   type == "peacock"
```

Comment: Yes you're right about @type (instance variable) but why is type (local variable) available in the is_a_peacock? method.

Comment: @Vizkrig: it's not a local variable, it's a method call.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Thanks, Please add this to your answer, so that I can accept it.

Answer (score 1):

> Why is the `type` variable available in the `is_a_peacock?` method in the following?

Your presupposition to this question does not hold. `type` inside the method body of `is_a_peacock?` is not a local variable. It is a method call.

> Why does commenting out the initialization of `@type` make `type` unavailable?

It does not. The method `type` is available, which returns the value of `@type`, which is `nil` by default.